# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{n^2+\sqrt{n}+n^p}$ diverges for what p?

Tags: calculus

So, here's question: For what values of $p$ does $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{n^2+\sqrt n+n^p}$$ diverge? I think it's using a test to compare to $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ and it diverges for $p<3$?

Comment: Please edit your question to add [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) in order to allow people to better answer your question and to prevent your question from being closed.

Comment: Is $p$ a real number or an integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you are incorrect to assume the $p$ test only works for $p\in\mathbb{N}$. In fact, the series will diverge for $p\leq 2$ and converge for $p>2$.

Proof: Let $p\leq 2$. Then

$$\frac{n+1}{n^2+\sqrt n+n^p}>\frac{n+0}{n^2+n^2+n^2}=\frac{1}{3n}$$

Thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{n^2+\sqrt n+n^p}\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3n}=\infty$$

For $p>2$ We have that

$$\frac{n+1}{n^2+\sqrt n+n^p}<\frac{n+n}{0+0+n^p}=\frac{2}{n^{p-1}}$$

Since $p-1>1$ we have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{n^2+\sqrt n+n^p}\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n^{p-1}}<\infty$$

Comment: Or even more generally, convergence occurs if $\Re p>2$.

Comment: Excellent answer, a quality I've often noticed in your posts. I've been wondering, how did you come up with your first inequality? Did it just seem obvious to you, or was there some sort of strategy that you used?

Comment: @A-Level_Student Since I knew I wanted to prove divergence, my strategy overall was to compare the fraction to something smaller that still diverged. Thats why I decreased the numerator and increased the denominator (so the whole expression decreased) in such a way as to simplify it to something that was previously known